# Range value changing when indexing a list backwards

Tags: python

I'm creating a chess game inside of Python (pygame) and in my validating moves function, I access a list of all possible moves.

However, as I'm removing from that list, I index it backwards. However, when I implement that change, the amount of repetitions undergone by the for loop encompassing the index changes from 20 to 1.

Here's the full function code:

```
def valid_move_2():
global white_to_move
possible_moves = generate_possible_moves()
print(range(len(possible_moves)))
for i in range(len(possible_moves)-1, -1, -1):
    print("possible moves range")
    print(str(possible_moves[i][0]))
    move(possible_moves[i][0], possible_moves[i][1], possible_moves[i][2], possible_moves[i][3])
    white_to_move = not white_to_move
    check_check()
    if check_check():
        possible_moves.remove(possible_moves[i])
    white_to_move = not white_to_move
    undo_move()
if len(possible_moves) == 0:
    if check_check():
        checkmate = True
    else:
        stalement = True
else:
    checkmate = False
    stalemate = False
return possible_moves
```

To be specific:

```
print(range(len(possible_moves)))
```

This line returns `20`.

However this line:

```
print("possible moves range")
```

only returns once, meaning the for loop repeats only once.

Where have I gone wrong?

THE ISSUE

The issue lies with this function, where my program gets stuck:

```
def square_under_attack(posx, posy):
print("SQUARE UNDER ATTACK FUNCTION CALLED")
global white_to_move
white_to_move = not white_to_move
enemy_moves = generate_possible_moves()
white_to_move = not white_to_move
x=0
for opponent_move in enemy_moves:
    print(x)
    if opponent_move[3] == posx and opponent_move[4] == posy:  # if the opponent can move to the square being tested
        print("returned true")
        return True
    x+=1
print("returned false")
return False
```

In this function, it gets stuck in the for loop. The x value was for troubleshooting to find out how many times the loop is iterated before not returning anything.

x is printed to have a value of 2 without either of the other 2 print functions being called at all.

What's wrong?

Comment: Its hard to tell when your indents are inconsistent.

Comment: I'd like to see what is generate_possible_moves() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(range(len(possible_moves)))
```

This shouldn't return 20.
It should return something like

`range(0,20)`

If so then it's problem of your for loop not range.

```
possible_moves.remove(possible_moves[i])
```

This line in particular is problematic.
If you are trying to remove i th element in possible_moves, use del

```
del possible_moves[i]
```

Also there are some dangerous bits in your code, one is global variable. Try to find another way to do that without using a global variable.

Another is your loop is iterated by initial length of possible_moves, and in the loop you are possibly removing something from possible_moves. This may cause index error. Easy fix would be to create a new list to keep track of what is deleted and what is not deleted.

If this doesn't solve error then there must be some issues in called method/functions

Try refactoring it with recursion since I think your iteration is very unorderly and possibly has repeated codes all over your code base.
If possible, use list comprehension instead of iteration to make things more concise.
If you want to do something like "Do until list L is empty" then use following pattern

```
while L:
    do_something()
```

For your problem, chess, I would design it like this:

First define a function for each chess pieces that returns a set of grids they can go on next turn.

For check and checkmate I would look for a union of all the sets which represents all their possible next moves.

I think you are trying to implement your program by trying out every single enemy moves and then undoing it which is incredibly inefficient approach

You should make all the methods very concise and atomic. You shouldn't make them convoluted and do many implicit things under the hood. Keep them simple and logically concise as much as possible

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I've found the root of the issue now and if you could see what I added at the bottom of my question that would be great :). Thank you again for your help, I greatly appreciate it!